# Is it better to sample more time points or more replicates at constant sample size?

Tags: regression, sampling, experiment-design, standard-error

I would like to analyze my data with a linear regression:

```
t*k = x
```

x is my measurement with some error

t is time

I want to fit k as best as I can with the best estimate of the standard error for k possible.
Question: For a fixed N, is it better (in terms of quality of fit and minimization of the standard error) to sample at different time points or N/k time points with k replicates at each time point ?

Details in case they are relevant:

These are physical measurements: someone comes in at time t and takes a measurement for each sample. The measurements are destructive so N replicates are prepared ahead of time. Both the replicates and the measurement process are "expensive" so we cannot have a large N (6 to 10 is typical).

People in my field like to see error bars on everything so N/k time points with error bars and then a linear fit to those N/k averages is the most intuitively pleasing to them, but I cannot help but feeling like we are loosing something doing it this way.

Comment: Welcome to CV.  For this model, the *mathematical* answer is to wait absolutely as long as you can and take all your measurements then.  I suspect you might be uncomfortable with that solution -- and there are plenty of potential reasons to be so.  But could you tell us some of those reasons, so that we might have more guidance concerning what solution you truly need?

Comment: It depends what your question is, and what kind of data you are acquiring.

Comment: @whuber interesting.  that makes some sense to me.  We have a guess but not a precise measurement at time 0 either so I assume splitting measurements between time 0 and tf is then more optimal.  I think the practical reason not to concentrate measurements at the final time is that we often don't know when that is.  we expect k to be negative and we have a limit on the sensitivity of our assay.   So x at tf may be low that we can't measure it accuatly and we just throw it out.

Comment: @caroZ I suspect that if i knew precisly what my question was I'd already have the asnwer.  But I know of no other way of getting closer to the right question than by asking the wrong question first and examining the answer to that.  "it depends..." is always the best answer I can hope to get from someone.

Comment: If you have a guess at time zero, then your model should instead be $E[x] = a + kt$ (including an intercept). In that case the mathematical answer is to split your data evenly between time $t=0$ and the maximum possible time.  But even then there are more considerations.  Are you really sure of this model?  Maybe the relationship is not linear, for example.  In that case you should collect some observations at intermediate times to check the linearity.  This is why it's so important to understand your *application* and not just focus on your mathematical model.